# Having trouble creating my Neural Network inputs

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm currently working on a neural network that should have $N$ parameters in input. Each parameters can have $M$ different values (discrete values), let's say $\{A,B,C,\dotsc,M\}$. It also has a discrete number of outputs.

How can I create my inputs from this situation? Should I have $N \times M$ inputs (having $0$ or $1$ as value), or should I think of a different approach?

Comment: Using $ N xM $ inputs is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is pretty commonly encountered in ML and is that of how to handle categorical inputs. First up, your inputs aren't parameters. Parameters in ML lingo are what you train.

And yes, the NxM approach is correct. Convert each of your categorical input variable into a 1XM vector of binary indicators giving you a NXM matrix of inputs. You can look up the literature on categorical input variables and I'm sure you will find that this is a standard approach used in many papers!

Hope it helps :)